# Java - Erro de Execução de Classe Principal

Tags: java, window-builder

Boa tarde,

Após usar o Eclipse Luna e voltar para Eclipse Mars simplesmente o negócio surtou até apaguei os arquivos do Eclipse para vê se resolvia e importei novamente o projeto do java mais continua dando o seguinte erro.

> (JFrame Acessar): "Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal view.Acessar"

Todos os outros JFrames estão com o mesmo problema.
Agora criei outro para fazer o teste e ele executa a janela ou seja abri a janela do programa. Embora eu não tenha feito qualquer modificação no código fonte dos JFrames o problema simplesmente surgiu. Não faço ideia de como resolver isso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acessar parece ser uma classe do seu projeto, isso é porque o Eclipse não deve ter reconhecido ou não foi setado o caminho do seu pacote, talvez porque tenha sido alterado, verifique o caminho do pacote.

Outra possivel situação que pode ter ocorrido é a versão do Java não estar configurado corretamente nessa mudança.

Faça a verificação também da importação da classe JFrame, se o Java reconhece ela como parte da API do Swing.

Uma ultima alternativa que conheço é ir na aba Project > Clean e escolher seu projeto para que o eclipse tente resolver os problemas de build.

Comment: Utilizei outro que eu tinha e resolveu o problema. Obrigado!!